# jquery slideshow

Tags: jquery, slideshow

I need a jquery slideshow with div popup

i want to show my image gallery in that slideshow.

I have three villas images in gallery

each with a set of 5 images.

when i click on the first villa image, that slideshow my show the rest of four including the one i click.

similary with other two villas.

i have stored the images of my villas in three different folders.

can any one show me any jquery for this...Please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at some of the hundreds of slide show jQuery plugins out there. Here is a nice list: http://bradblogging.com/jquery/9-jquery-slideshow-applications-you-cannot-miss/

Comment: What do you mean by "div" pop ups. What is the preference for?

Comment: These almost all do that. It is the modal  effect. I know lightbox does for sure, one of the more popular. Here is the lightbox in action. http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ Just click on an image.

Answer (score 0):

Try the easy slider or light box to get the soultion which you expect